# TypeScript and immediate functions

Tags: typescript

I'm playing around with TypeScript and would like to have Douglas Crawfords json_parse method as part of my code, however it is an immediate function that returns a function.
Of course I could just have the code as JavaScript and have a .d.ts file but how would I go about exporting the result of an immediate function?

Something like this:

```
module blim.blam {
    export function json_parse = (function() {
        return function() {};
    })();
}
```

Is that at all possible?

Comment: Or ``module blim.blam { export function json_parse() { return function() {}; } }``

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to fix the syntax error that you are getting by replace `function` with `var`. So :

```
module blim.blam {
    export var json_parse = (function() {
        return function() {};
    })();
}
```

The reason is because the following is a syntax error in TypeScript ***and*** JavaScript:

```
function foo = function(){}
```

The proper syntax in both languages is :

```
var foo = function(){}
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you can do something like this instead:

```
module blim.blam {
    export var json_parse:Function = function() {};
}
```

Hope that works for you.